# Kibana start fail with the error [ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with ‘security_exception

Tags: kibana

when i start kibana ,i get the error

```
[2022-03-22T07:38:57.371+00:00][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS -> UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS. took: 32015ms.
[2022-03-22T07:38:57.372+00:00][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/mapping/put] is unauthorized for user [elastic] with roles [superuser] on indices [.kibana_task_manager_8.0.0_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 6 in 64 seconds.
[2022-03-22T07:38:57.373+00:00][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS -> UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS. took: 32003ms.
[2022-03-22T07:40:01.376+00:00][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/mapping/put] is unauthorized for user [elastic] with roles [superuser] on indices [.kibana_8.0.0_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 7 in 64 seconds.
[2022-03-22T07:40:01.376+00:00][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS -> UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS. took: 64005ms.
[2022-03-22T07:40:01.377+00:00][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/mapping/put] is unauthorized for user [elastic] with roles [superuser] on indices [.kibana_task_manager_8.0.0_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 7 in 64 seconds.
[2022-03-22T07:40:01.377+00:00][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS -> UPDATE_TARGET_MAPPINGS. took: 64005ms.
```

is anybody help me?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?